# How to manage multiple build schemes for an app which supports to Push Notification and InAppPurchase..?

Tags: ios, iphone, push-notification, in-app-purchase, xcode10

I have a app with two different debug configuration with two schemes , every scheme managed with suffix to create two different app on a device for same target. Its working fine but the problem is because of two different bundle identifier one of these app is unable to receive push notification.

is there any way two get push notification for both app in this scenario..? also same for In App Purchase .

Finally I created another certificate to support push notification in both. Is there any other simple way ..?

Answer (score 0):

You need to create separate apps for the different schemes in App Store Connect. The push notifications and in-app purchases will need to be configured for each app.

The simpler way is to use a single bundle Id :)

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, but I already tried in this way means created another certificate and configure for another app. But is it the only way (treating both schemes as separate app) or is there any other ways..without creating extra certificate and extra app configuration?